# Errors in Chrome://gpu after the Jan 06, 2021, updates for 20.04.1

Tags: google-chrome, gpu-driver, mesa, drm

I am using Xubuntu 20.04.1. Kernel: 5.4.0-59.

The January 06, 2021 updates included **video drivers**, **mesa** and **drm** updates that are now causing the following repetitive errors in **Chrome://gpu** (Chrome 87.0.4280.88)

```
WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(48)] : ProgramGL.cpp:990 (checkLinkStatus): Program link or binary loading failed with no info log.
ERROR:shared_context_state.cc(74)] : Skia shader compilation error ------------------------ Errors:
```

Do we know anything about them please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the latest Chrome update (87.0.4280.141) fixed the issue. I don't see the errors mentioned above anymore.